# How to make it so it reads value instead of name in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm making a Multiple Choice Question Website for a event im holding with little knowledge of php since I need it to input the data into a text file.

```
<?php
    extract($_REQUEST);
    $file=fopen("form-save.txt","a");

    fwrite($file,"name :");
    fwrite($file, $username ."\n");
    fwrite($file,"Email :");
    fwrite($file, $email ."\n");
    fwrite($file,"Password :");
    fwrite($file, $password ."\n");
    fclose($file);
    header("location: index.php");
 ?>
```

so I came across this code ^, the variables $username, $email and $password's inputs are taken off the **name=** part code below.

```
<div class="inputQ1">
            <input type="radio" id="A1" name="Ad1" value="A1" >
            <label for="A1">A1</label><br>
        </div>
```

What I want is to read the **value=** instead of the **name=** if the names are not the same for all input, you can select more than one input which is not what I want.

Any suggestions is lovely :D

Comment: from the php docs: warning: Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input

Comment: Depending on your location it may be illegal to store passwords in plain text and some salt/pepper hashing or encryption is required.

Comment: The use of it isnt for password it is for storing of multiple choice question answers

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h2>There are two option for you </h2>
<h3>Select only one option </h3>
<div class="inputQ1">
<input type="radio" id="A1" name="Ad1" value="A1" >
<label for="A1">A1</label>
</div>
<div class="inputQ1">
<input type="radio" id="A1" name="Ad1" value="A2" >
<label for="A1">A2</label>
<div class="inputQ1">
<input type="radio" id="A1" name="Ad1" value="A3" >
<label for="A1">A3</label>
</div>
<h3>Select Multiple option</h3>
<div class="inputQ1">
<input type="radio" id="A1" name="Ad1" value="A1" >
<label for="A1">A1</label>
</div>
<div class="inputQ1">
<input type="radio" id="A1" name="Ad2" value="A2" >
<label for="A1">A2</label>
<div class="inputQ1">
<input type="radio" id="A1" name="Ad3" value="A3" >
<label for="A1">A3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: ID has to be different

Comment: This answer does not attempt to answer the OP's question

Comment: You can't unselect the multiple radios.